# unable to use xepersian on newest texlive

Tags: xepersian, texlive-2016

Why i can't use `xepersian` package ?
I'm using newest version of texlive (2016.20170123-5) on emacs.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\fontspec{B Lotus}

\usepackage{xepersian}

\begin{document}
hi !
\end{document}
```

emacs show me this error : [image]

Comment: Works fine for (if I add a font). Are you sure that your system is up-to-date? Imho `\__fontspec_pass_args:nnn` has been removed from a current fontspec, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350664/todays-fontspec-update-breaking-fontspec-pass-args

Comment: Dear @Ulrike.. thanks for your response. What's your point about "up-to-date" ? i just installed full tex-live and don't know what else should be done.

Comment: Run the texlive manager: `tlmgr update --list` and check if there updates.

Comment: copied from terminal : Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /root/texmf!
cannot setup TLPDB in /root/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5713.

Comment: Did you install a standalone texlive or something from your linux distribuation?

Comment: i installed texlive-full , emacs and auctex ... my os is Kali Linux

Comment: Sorry I have windows. Imho your texsystem is not up-to-date, but I can't tell you how you can update in your system.

Comment: Thank you so much... i resume my googling to find what is not updated... i will post the answer and cause of the problem :)

Comment: Consider to install texlive directly instead of using the packages, as these often lag behind. See https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html , Section "Integrating vanilla TeX Live with Debian"

Comment: Thank you @gernot, the problem is bad installation and using debian packages for installing texlive !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is bad installation of TexLive (using debian packages). The Correct way is to install from ctan.org. I just downloaded an iso image from ctan mirrors and every thing just works ! Thank you @gernot & @Ulrike Fischer for your helpful comments.